# Extracting user-specific values from hidden inputs

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to upload, rename a file, then send to dB, so I can display the cropped image.  In order for the cropped image to correspond to the user who's logged in, I need to include user specific data in hidden input fields.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form id="cropimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="change_pic.php">
    <strong>Upload Image:</strong> <br><br>
    <input type="file" name="profile-pic" id="profile-pic" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hdn-profile-id" id="hdn-profile-id" value="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="username-id" id="username-id" value="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hdn-x1-axis" id="hdn-x1-axis" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hdn-y1-axis" id="hdn-y1-axis" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hdn-x2-axis" value="" id="hdn-x2-axis" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hdn-y2-axis" value="" id="hdn-y2-axis" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hdn-thumb-width" id="hdn-thumb-width" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hdn-thumb-height" id="hdn-thumb-height" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="" id="action" />
    <input type="hidden" name="image_name" value="" id="image_name" />
    <div id='preview-profile-pic'></div>
    <div id="thumbs" style="padding:5px; width:600p"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The form is being captured here:

```
function changeProfilePic() {
$post = isset($_POST) ? $_POST: array();
$max_width = "500"; 
$userId = isset($post['hdn-profile-id']) ? intval($post['hdn-profile-id']) : 0;
$username = isset($post['username-id']);
$path = 'assets/images/tmp';
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg");
$name = $_FILES['profile-pic']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['profile-pic']['size'];
if(strlen($name)) {
    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) {
        if($size<(1024*1024)) {
            $actual_image_name = 'avatar' . '_' . $username.'_'.$userId .'.'.$ext;  
///etc,etc...
```

What I'm trying to do is get to the build `$actual_image_name = 'avatar' . '_' . $username.'_'.$userId .'.'.$ext;`

The problem is, `$username` is always outputting as `1` vs the persons username.  So file names that I'm getting are `avatar_1_11.jpg` when they should be `avatar_john_smith_11.jpg`

I don't understand.  If the value of the hidden input is `<?php echo $user['username']; ?>` and I'm retrieving that based on `id` in `function changeProfilePic()`, why would it be evaluating to 1?  Am I retrieving this incorrectly?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on hidden fields, but instead use the session data, as it can't be modified by the end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset()` is returning `true`:

```
$username = isset($post['username-id']);
```

Which converts to string `1` when you concatenate it into `$actual_image_name`:

```
$actual_image_name = 'avatar' . '_' . $username.'_'.$userId .'.'.$ext;
```

You can do it as you did for the other variable:

```
$username = isset($post['username-id']) ? $post['username-id'] : '';
```

However, why would it be the case that it is not set and how should you handle that?

Comment: exactly.  I don't wth I have `isset()` there.  I dumped it and added `md5(time())` to the build and it's good to go.